# Add Properties to an External Object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I import an external library and want to add a new property to a passed in parameter. I have to call the object using `(<any>conv.data)` or the compiler gives `Object is of type 'unknown'.`.

I wonder is there a better way of doing this?

```js
import { dialogflow, Permission } from 'actions-on-google';

const app = dialogflow({ debug: true });

app.intent('actions_intent_PERMISSION', (conv, _, permissionGranted) => {
  if (!permissionGranted) {
    conv.ask('Bye Bye!')
  } else {
    (<any>conv.data).userName = conv.user.name.display
    conv.ask(`Thanks, ${(<any>conv.data).userName}.`)
  }
})
```

Comment: What is the type of `conv`? Your code suggests you do have type information for it...?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have type information for `conv`. It should have `data` defined somehow; if not, the best thing would be to update the type information so it defines `data`. At worst, `data` could be defined as `any`, but it would be better if you can define the properties it should (or can) have (optional ones can be defined as optional, of course). Or define it as `[key: string]: any`, but that doesn't buy you much over `any`.

If you don't have type information for `conv`, you can define it yourself. For instance:

```
interface Conv {
    ask(msg: string): void;
    data: {[key:string]: any};
    user: {
        name: {
            display: appropriateTypeHere;
       }
    }
}
```